# Mail sent with php mail not showing up

Tags: php, linux, apache, debian

I have recently changed my OS from Ubuntu 11.10 to Debian 7.0.0 due to some problems I was having with Ubuntu.  I have set up LAMP using Apache 2.  Most things appear to be working about the same but mail, which was working fine on Ubuntu, is now not working properly.  I use the following code.

```
    $mailDelivery=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    if ($mailDelivery)
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Mail delivery successful");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Mail delivery failed");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
```

I checked the input arguments to mail() and they are the same as the ones that worked successfully on Ubuntu.  Also, the alert box returns

```
Mail delivery successful
```

However, the mail does not show up at the address (which is one of my on-line addresses).

I looked at php.ini and it has the following lines

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
```

There is nothing about mail delivery in /var/log/apache2/error.log.

I also checked my spam folder at the destination email address and there was nothing there.

I also transferred the iptables from Ubuntu to Debian by doing

```
iptables-save >iptables.save
```

on Ubuntu, copying iptables.save over and

```
iptables-restore <iptables.save
```

I also did the following calls with the following results.

```
peter@app-server:/var/www$ sudo cat /var/log/mail.err
peter@app-server:/var/www$ sudo cat /var/log/mail.log
peter@app-server:/var/www$ sudo cat /var/log/mail.warn
peter@app-server:/var/www$ sudo cat /var/log/mail.info
peter@app-server:/var/www$
```

Comment: Check you log files in /var/log/mail* as this is not an issue with apache nor PHP.

Comment: That's a good suggestion.  Unfortunately it did not show anything.  I have just appended that test, and its results, to the end of my question.  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: I'm not sure about debian log files. Did you check /var/log/mail/ as well? What MTA do you use? In the mail logs you should see something about a) attemps to deliver, b) succesful deliveries and c) failed deliveries. What is the output of `netstat -tulpen | grep ':25'`

Comment: Thank you for your help but it appears that the problem was fixed by my installing the SMTP server.  It appears that Ubuntu installs a lot of packages by default while Debian leaves them up to the user to install.

Comment: That is ecactly what I was pointing  you to. The netstat command above checks if there actually is a SMTPD running on your system. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I found the source of my problem.  I had not installed the SMTP server.  I ran

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

and that fixed the problem.